# Unable to initialize yadcf filter when scrolling enabled

Tags: yadcf

I'm trying to use yacdf (0.9.3) for the first time with DataTables (1.10.16). I'm using DataTables built in scrolling for both horizontal and vertical scrolling of my table.

Either way (old or new DataTables API) I try to initialize the filter when scrolling enabled I end up with  Uncaught TypeError:

> Cannot read property 'oScroll' of null!

```
var table = $(".jqDataTable").DataTable({
    dom: 'frti',
    scrollY: "460px",
    scrollCollapse: true,
    scrollX: true,
    paging: false
    });
yadcf.init(table, [{column_number : 3}]);


Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oScroll' of null
    at scrollXYHandler (jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js.jsf?ln=js:3696)
    at initAndBindTable (jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js.jsf?ln=js:3719)
    at Object.init (jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js.jsf?ln=js:3938)
```

However when scrolling disabled the filter gets initialized.

I feel stuck with the problem.

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle test page so I will be able to check it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/758597/ I cannot reproduce the error on JSFiddle and also I cannot make the app URL public where I actually have the issue. Do you have an idea what should I look for in my app to identify to root cause?

Comment: Is it possible to map similar values to one search label in the select filter? On above JSFiddle link I tried adding `data: [{value: ['O/N', 'S/N'], label: 'Overnight'}]` but it's not working.

Comment: no, but you can use `filter_type: 'custom_func'` read docs and see showcase (first column - http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source.html ) it will allow you to do very customized filtering